Weighted average value for five-point scale survey question
I have a survey question which has response choices on a 5-point scale.
The response choices are:
Not at all, Barely, A bit, Almost always, Completely.
We've assigned a value to each response, ranging from 0 to 4.
We were calculating a metric to find the "average" value for the question, and the "percentage average value".
Here is a sample table



Response
Value
Number of responses
Total value




Not at all
0
20
$0\times 20 = 0$


Barely
1
50
$1\times 50 = 50$


A bit
2
30
$2\times 30 = 60$


Almost always
3
60
$3\times 60 = 180$


Completely
4
40
$4\times 40 = 160$



So the average value will be equal to $\frac{0+50+60+180+160}{20+50+30+60+40} = 2.25$.
Then the "percentage average value" will be equal to $\frac{2.25}{4} =  56.25$%.
The reason I'm asking, is to confirm if this makes "mathematical sense", to find the "average" response value of a survey question. As well, I only divided by 4, because it makes sense to if it's on a scale from 0 to 4. But I'm unsure what happens if the scale changes to something like 3,4,5,6,7.  What would I divide by?
Or even if it changes to: 3,5,8,9,10 for whatever reason.
It makes sense for me to divide by 4 because it means the final result ranges from 0% to 100%, no matter what the survey responses are. I'm a bit more unsure what happens if the scale isn't uniform, and doesn't start at 0.

Converting a Likert scale into a numerical scale is fraught with interpretation issues. A better approach to average here is to get all of your responses to this question and identify the modal response - the one with the highest count. Then your average might be "a bit" or "almost always" say, which makes much more sense.
